# Laravel: Why hasMany related objects are not sent with object to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In Laravel, when a function returned an object to a view, the 'hasMany' related objects are not sent with object.

This is a controller function code:

```
return Response::json(array('success'=>true, 'res'=>Group::find($group->id)->toArray()));
```

And that is the output:

```
{"success":true,"res":{"id":18,"title":"My PCs","notes":"This is my PCs.","user_id":1}}
```

This is the relation function in the Model of Group:

```
public function devices() {
        return $this->hasMany('Device');
}
```

Why I can't get the devices of group object in the view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [eager or lazy load](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) the relation first:

```
// lazy load if you already fetched the $group
$group->load('devices');

return Response::json(array('success'=>true, 'res'=>$group->toArray()));


// eager load when fetching the $group
$group = Group::with('devices')->find($someId);

return Response::json(array('success'=>true, 'res'=>$group->toArray()));
```